# I am getting "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required on python 3.6.1 while installing pocketsphinx

Tags: python, visual-c++, python-3.6, pocketsphinx

I am new to python. While installing `pocketsphinx` on python 3.6.1 I'm getting

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools"

I checked on the link provided to install visual c++ build tools, its size comes to GBs.

Is there any other alternative so that I can skip downloading GB's and get my work done? I would prefer not to install VS as I work on eclipse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Answer (score 1):

You must download the native libraries of Sphinx to do your work regardless of the IDE. And it's not VS, it's C++

Python only *wraps* some external code that you need to install first since you're not using a pure Python library

You can even see the dependencies listed here.

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/blob/master/readme.md

Answer (score 0):

Actually this problem still persists in ***2021***. But I got a way out after I downloaded the [source code of pocketsphinx](https://pypi.org/project/pocketsphinx/#modal-close) from pypi website. The source code is packed in a .gz file , so, extract that archive. From the extracted folder just copy two folders - **pocketsphinx**, **sphinxbase** to C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\  . And that's it, import it in your project.