# pip install -U steem error Windows Kits

Tags: python, windows, pip, failed-installation

I am still trying to install steem via the "pip install -U steem"-command. 
I already did what David suggested in this thread [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required), which means that I installed the Microsoft Visual package he linked there and ran the installation command again.

The error I get now is the following:

```
     creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cip
her
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Ciph
er
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Ci
pher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Ci
pher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Ciph
er
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Uti
l
copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Util
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random
copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random

copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cry
pto\Random
copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Rand
om
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd
64-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64
-3.6\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cryp
to\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cry
pto\Random\Fortuna
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypt
o\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Rand
om\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\R
andom\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypt
o\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypt
o\Random\OSRNG
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\S
elfTest
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Se
lfTest
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cryp
to\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cr
ypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\C
rypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\C
rypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3
.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\C
rypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cr
ypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\C
rypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3
.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64
-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cr
ypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cr
ypto\SelfTest\Cipher
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cry
pto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cryp
to\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cryp
to\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cryp
to\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\C
rypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cryp
to\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\C
rypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\C
rypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\C
rypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\C
rypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cryp
to\SelfTest\Hash
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-a
md64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64
-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\
Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-
3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\
Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64
-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd
64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd6
4-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win
-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cr
ypto\SelfTest\Random
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> bui
ld\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build
\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-
amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd6
4-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-a
md64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-am
d64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3
.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd6
4-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-
amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-
3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cry
pto\SelfTest\Util
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\
Crypto\SelfTest\Util
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\C
rypto\SelfTest\Util
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.
6\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Cryp
to\SelfTest\Util
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd6
4-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd
64-3.6\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypt
o\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Pr
otocol
copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Protoco
l
copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Pr
otocol
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Public
Key
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Pu
blicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Pub
licKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Public
Key
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Publi
cKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Publi
cKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\
PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\P
ublicKey
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\
Signature
copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto
\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Crypto\S
ignature
Skipping optional fixer: buffer
Skipping optional fixer: idioms
Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
running build_ext
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastm
ath.
building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe
/c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -Ic:\users\***\
appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\***\appdata\loca
l\programs\python\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft     Visual St
udio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include    \10.0.102
40.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared"     "-IC:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files     (x86)\Windows K
its\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release    \src/
winrand.obj
winrand.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
26): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
27): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
28): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
30): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
30): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
40): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
41): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
41): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
41): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
42): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
45): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
46): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
46): error C2059: syntax error: ','
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
48): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
50): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
56): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
63): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
69): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
76): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
82): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
89): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(
95): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B
IN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\***\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u
-c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\***AN~1\\AppData\\Local    \\
Temp\\pip-build-9e4h7q1o\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',     open)(
__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code,     __fil
e__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\***AN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-    gfrm999
1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile"     faile
d with error code 1 in C:\Users\***AN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-    9e4h7q1o\p
ycrypto\

C:\Users\***>pi
```

Is there anything wrong with the code of the preinstalled Windows-packages or what's the problem? I hope you have some idea, thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install Python? How did you install `pip`?

Comment: I installed Python 3 with the Windows x86-64 executable installer from the official site and some time later i also installed Python 2, but it is Python 3 that is run by default. 
And unfortunately I have no idea how I installed pip, I can't even remember doing so. 
Any suggestions though?

Comment: The [steem documentation](http://steem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) recommends using [Anaconda](http://steem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) to install `steem`. I was unable to install `steem` using python.org Python and Visual C++ 14.0.

Comment: I was able to install `steem` on [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). However, I knew what I was doing and I had to install a lot of extra dependencies (e.g. gcc, autoconf, automake, bison, flex, python3-devel, openssl-devel). I know how to do this because I've used Cygwin for years and I know the drill. I wouldn't recommend it to someone who is not familiar with Cygwin.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that what I tried didn't work out for you either? (I'm making sure because I'd feared that there had gone something wrong especially with my programms.) 
No, the alternative with cygwin probably wouldn't be a good solution for me except there was a clear instrunction how to deal with it. 
So what can I do now? Shall I deinstall my both pythons and then reinstall them with Anaconda? I'm afraid there could go something wrong with the deinstallation so that the reinstallation wouldn't work because of remaining packages or something.

Comment: Yes. I used a Windows 7 VM to duplicate your environment and I discovered a limitation in Visual C++ 14.0 that prevented the build from succeeding. Then I did what I should have done first: I read the documentation for how to install `steem` on Windows. I think you can install Anaconda side-by-side with your existing Python installations.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for all your efforts! Then I'll just try to install Anaconda and let you know if it worked out afterwards.