# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required when installing python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, c++14, statsmodels

I’m trying to download the package `statsmodels` by running in command prompt(admin) this command:

```
pip3 install statsmodels
```

and I get this error

> “error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools”

Please note that I already installed Visual Studio 2015 and I also have Visual Studio 2013 installed on my machine.

Comment: Try:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/7976758

Comment: I finally got to solve this issue as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55575792/1612432

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Answer (score 23):

1. Please download [Visual C++ Build Tools 2015](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126)
2. Install the **visualcppbuildtools_full** from 1.
3. Please ensure below dependencies were installed:
   Python later then 2.6, including Python 3.x, NumPy, SciPy, Pandas, Patsy, Cython
4. After all the dependencies and **visualcppbuildtools_full** are installed, please relaunch your IDE or reboot computer.
5. Please execute "pip3 install statsmodels" again after IDE relaunch.

I'm using Windows VS code, and I found the statsmodels installation won't work unless I relaunch my VS code.

Please try it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I am too late to share a solution here but it might help someone in the future.
i was also trying to setup YOLO and was trying for a complete one day to solve the VC++ error message.

Command i was trying to run: **python setup.py build_ext --inplace** 
Error message everyone knows: **Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required**
so i google it visit many forums and tried everything, from reinstalling VC++ tools for VS2015 many times and restart my system many times, set paths in environment variables.
but none worked for me...

what worked for me>>>>?

1: Install VC++ build tools from [build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017), once you run the setup, check only **Visual C++ build tools** and select all important optional check boxes on the right side. it might take more than 8 GB on your desk, then restart your system.

2: Add path in Environment Variables to your VC that will be: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC

3: Also add path to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726 with variable name: `VS140COMNTOOLS`

4:Once its done type **Native Tools** in windows start menu. you should see **X64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2017** click on it, it will open a command prompt, run your command again inside this command prompt not in regular windows command prompt.

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the visual c++ ***build tools***. The link in the error message seems like it's dead, but you can download them here: ***https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/***

Comment: How to do this via regular windows cmd?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error but on a UWP app build.
Nothing helped until I uninstalled all Visual Studios and installed Visual Studio again setting component according to the official [docs about VC 140](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/c-runtime-packages-desktop-bridge#how-to-install-and-update-desktop-framework-packages)