# Pip error even Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is installed

Tags: python-3.x, visual-c++, pip, airflow

I read all of the questions and answers which are related or asked before and I still didn't find an appropriate answer to my problem.

I am using python 3.6.5 and pip(and setuptools) is up to date.
I am installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 from here: 
https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

when using pip install, I still get the error:

> Microsoft Visual C++ is required

PS: I want to install airflow

Answer (score 17):

This problem was solved on a computer having Visual Studio Community 2017 v15.5.2 and the Visual Studio Installer v1.16.1247.518 installed.

The steps used are as follows:

1. Start the Visual Studio Installer
2. Visual Studio Installer showed a Installed section that stated that Visual
   Studio Community 2017. In that section was a drop-down titled More. The drop-
   down option Modify was selected.
3. Visual Studio Installer then showed "tabs" titled Workloads, Individual
   components, Language packs and Installed locations.  The tab "***Individual components***" was selected.
4. Scrolling down the list of Individual components, there was a section titled
   Compilers, build tools, and runtimes. Under that section there was a VC++
   2015.3 v140 toolset for desktop (x86,x64) option that was unchecked. The
   option was then checked.
5. The Modify button located at the lower right part of the Visual Studio
   Installer was pushed.
6. After waiting an unreasonably long amount of time, the installer finished
   modifying the installation of Visual Studio Community 2017.

As always, your mileage may differ.

Answer (score 1):

As per instructions here: https://www.scivision.co/python-windows-visual-c++-14-required/

Use vs_buildtools.exe and install only the windows 10 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

*Visual C++ Redistributable* installs run-time libraries and can be used to run applications written with VC. But you need Visual C++ **compiler**! So install [Build Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [using MinGW as the C compiler](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers).