# pip install fbprophet - error: "io.h: No such file or directory error: command 'cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, facebook-prophet

I am trying to install for python (anaconda, windows) package: "fbprofit".
At the first stage I've got error: [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required - error - pip install fbprophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51460318/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-error-pip-install-fbprophet)
but now it seems to be resolved (thanks to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/7976758)), and there is another error:

```
    c:\work\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: ?? г¤ ?вбп RвЄа
лвм д c< ўЄ<оз?-Ё?: io.h: No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B
IN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I see that there are many similar questions here for different python packages under windows. 
Still I cannot get the solution.

I tried:

1) Launching pip install from Visual Studio 2017/Visual Studio Tools/ command promt  - otherwise (from other "cmd") I got another error.
(That is suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918595/625396 - that seems good idea !)

2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563421/625396
That does not seems to have any effect, strangely it worked for many people

3) https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/148
Here is suggested to download precompiled wheels,
I have installed relevant to my machine: Twisted‑18.7.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
but it does not have an effect

Comment: Also asked here: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/2 still no answer

Comment: [Installation instructions for fbprophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html) say you need to [install PyStan](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_beginner.html).

Comment: @phd Yes, I know. I have done that, may be something is wrong, but I cannot understand what.  I just checked: pip install pystan --- returns that all requirments are satisfied: ------  Requirement already satisfied: pystan in c:\work\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.
17.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in c:\work\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
 (from pystan) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython!=0.25.1,>=0.22 in c:\work\anaconda3\lib\si
te-packages (from pystan) (0.28.2)