# Python - Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip

I can't install any packages with pip.
It says install Microsoft Visual C++ build tools.
I installed that but it's still not working (see pic)

[image]

And it's 2015 version because version 2017 could not install.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip error even Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610212/pip-error-even-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-installed)

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required