# installing magic-wormhole gives error code 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip

when doing `pip install magic-wormhole`
It gives the following error
`Command "c:\users\[Censured]\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\[Censured]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c9sttv8x\\twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\[Censured]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7opo58sr\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\[Censured]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c9sttv8x\twisted\`

Full log here: https://pastebin.com/iGVT5GyZ

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/7976758

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the very end of logs you will find lines:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
```

So, you have to  download and install  it.
It is available from official site: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/visual-cpp-build-tools