# python and ephem install

Tags: python, pip, pyephem

I am new to python. Have installed python ver 3.7.3, visual studio and build tools. Have executed the command 'python -m pip install -U pip setuptools' before installing the ephem. The following message is displayed and ephem install fails:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
>
> Command
>   "c:\users\aomine\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Aomine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-eouyp2bg\ephem\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\Aomine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_98cs8eb\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Aomine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-eouyp2bg\ephem\

Answer (score 1):

There are precompiled binary wheels [at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ephem/3.7.6.0/#files) (this is where from `pip` downloads packages) for Python 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4 If you downgrade your Python you can install one of them without compilation.

If you insist on using Python 3.7 you have to [install MS Visual C++ 14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610212/pip-error-even-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-installed/50671800#50671800). See also https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers.

BTW, do you know [PyEphem is deprecated](https://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/#alas-pyephem-is-deprecated)? The last release was in 2015. The author recommends 2 alternatives: https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/ and http://www.astropy.org/.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will be exploring 'Skyfield'.