# Error while installing Jupyter on Windows 10

Tags: python, jupyter, setup.py

I am getting the following error while Installing Jupyter through

> pip install jupyter

Below is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wxq2b1yw\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wxq2b1yw\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wxq2b1yw\pywinpty\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wxq2b1yw\pywinpty\
    Complete output (161 lines):
    Compiling C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Plex\Scanners.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Plex\Actions.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py because it changed.
    Compiling C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py because it changed.
    [1/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py
    [2/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py
    [3/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py
    [4/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py
    [5/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Plex\Actions.py
    [6/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Plex\Scanners.py
    [7/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Runtime\refnanny.pyx
    [8/8] Cythonizing C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
    warning: no files found matching 'Doc\*'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Debugger\Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython\Utility'
    warning: no files found matching 'pyximport\README'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
        cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
        self.run_command(cmdname)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
        self.build()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 205, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
        objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
        self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
        self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\setup.py", line 228, in <module>
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-019202gj\Cython-0.29.14\setup.py", line 228, in <module>
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wxq2b1yw\pywinpty\setup.py", line 68, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.`  I'd address that first, following the link in the error message.

Comment: I had installed the specified Microsoft Visual C++ version from the link but still getting same error.

Comment: Make sure you selected/included the Build Tools in the installation options. If you already installed MS VS C++ but it's still not working, see [Pip error even Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49610212/2745495).