# Error on installing Python package with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, pip, installation

I am trying to install eif package, used for extended isolation forest algorithm, but the installation is failing. I get this error on trying pip install eif or pip install git+https://github.com/sahandha/eif.git:

How can I install the library properly?

Collecting git+https://github.com/sahandha/eif.git
  Cloning https://github.com/sahandha/eif.git to c:\users\iulyd\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-he0z1rvd
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/sahandha/eif.git 'C:\Users\iulyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-he0z1rvd'
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in d:\anaconda_install\lib\site-packages (from eif==2.0.2) (1.16.5)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in d:\anaconda_install\lib\site-packages (from eif==2.0.2) (0.29.13)
Building wheels for collected packages: eif

```
  Building wheel for eif (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\Anaconda_install\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\iulyd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-he0z1rvd\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\iulyd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-he0z1rvd\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\iulyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-asla68oq' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\iulyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-he0z1rvd\
  Complete output (21 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying eif_old.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  running egg_info
  creating eif.egg-info
  writing eif.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to eif.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to eif.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to eif.egg-info\top_level.txt
  writing manifest file 'eif.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file 'eif.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'eif.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  cythoning _eif.pyx to _eif.cpp
  building 'eif' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for eif
  Running setup.py clean for eif
Failed to build eif
Installing collected packages: eif
    Running setup.py install for eif ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\Anaconda_install\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\iulyd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-he0z1rvd\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\iulyd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-he0z1rvd\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\iulyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hyzyr_un\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\iulyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-he0z1rvd\
    Complete output (19 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying eif_old.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running egg_info
    writing eif.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to eif.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to eif.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to eif.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'eif.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'eif.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    skipping '_eif.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'eif' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\Anaconda_install\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\iulyd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-he0z1rvd\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\iulyd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-he0z1rvd\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\iulyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hyzyr_un\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error even Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610212/pip-error-even-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-installed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: @phd I solved the issue by installing a previous version of eif: pip install eif==1.0.2 . I think the problem is with the newest version.

Comment: The difference is that [`eif`==1.0.2](https://github.com/sahandha/eif/tree/755488507ce8f507fe1f12dcf7d730813431557c) is pure Python so you can install it without a C/C++ compiler while [`eif`==2.0.2](https://github.com/sahandha/eif/tree/b50f8081df06e5f692bfbb9e7d7937a10f37ccc4) has code written in Cython and converted to C++ so you need a compiler for it. It's not a "problem", you just need a compiler. The compiler for w32 is M$ VC.