# installing external library on windows 10 goes wrong

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install the contractions package (https://pypi.org/project/contractions/) but this error keeps coming up.
Tried installing the Microsoft Visual C++ but it only downloads an installer and then I can't find the specific thing. Can someone help me figure this out?

EDIT: I obviously also tried with just `pip install contractions` and also with the `wheel` doc.

```
C:\Users\CatKa\Documents\MSc\MACHINE LEARNING>python -m pip install contractions
Collecting contractions
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/41/c3dfd5feb91a8d587ed1a59f553f07c05f95ad4e5d00ab78702fbf8fe48a/contractions-0.0.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting textsearch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/a8/03407021f9555043de5492a2bd7a35c56cc03c2510092b5ec018cae1bbf1/textsearch-0.0.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyahocorasick
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/9f/f0d8e8850e12829eea2e778f1c90e3c53a9a799b7f412082a5d21cd19ae1/pyahocorasick-1.4.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Unidecode in c:\users\catka\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from textsearch->contractions) (1.1.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyahocorasick
  Building wheel for pyahocorasick (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5amje9u5\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5amje9u5\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ky0_mxbr' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5amje9u5\pyahocorasick\
  Complete output (5 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'ahocorasick' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyahocorasick
  Running setup.py clean for pyahocorasick
Failed to build pyahocorasick
Installing collected packages: pyahocorasick, textsearch, contractions
    Running setup.py install for pyahocorasick ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5amje9u5\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5amje9u5\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-69ndyre4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5amje9u5\pyahocorasick\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'ahocorasick' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5amje9u5\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5amje9u5\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-69ndyre4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

EDIT 2:
Installed the Visual C++ like it says (https://www.scivision.co/python-windows-visual-c-14-required/) and also installed Visual C++ 14.0 as provided here ([Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)) but now the error part is even bigger

```
C:\Users\CatKa\Documents\MSc\MACHINE LEARNING>pip install contractions
Collecting contractions
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/41/c3dfd5feb91a8d587ed1a59f553f07c05f95ad4e5d00ab78702fbf8fe48a/contractions-0.0.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting textsearch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/a8/03407021f9555043de5492a2bd7a35c56cc03c2510092b5ec018cae1bbf1/textsearch-0.0.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Unidecode in c:\users\catka\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from textsearch->contractions) (1.1.1)
Collecting pyahocorasick
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/9f/f0d8e8850e12829eea2e778f1c90e3c53a9a799b7f412082a5d21cd19ae1/pyahocorasick-1.4.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyahocorasick
  Building wheel for pyahocorasick (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\catka\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nx9373pl\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nx9373pl\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-mg8rchse' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\
  Complete output (23 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'ahocorasick' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DAHOCORASICK_UNICODE= -Ic:\users\catka\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\catka\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" /Tcpyahocorasick.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyahocorasick.obj
  pyahocorasick.c
  c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\Automaton_pickle.c(363): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
  c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\Automaton_pickle.c(422): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
  c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\Automaton_pickle.c(473): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
  c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\Automaton_pickle.c(483): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
  c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\src/custompickle/load/loadbuffer.c(68): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
  c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\src/custompickle/load/module_automaton_load.c(89): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  creating C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\catka\anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\catka\anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_ahocorasick build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyahocorasick.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ahocorasick.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ahocorasick.cp37-win_amd64.lib
  pyahocorasick.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_ahocorasick' specified multiple times; using first specification
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ahocorasick.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ahocorasick.cp37-win_amd64.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyahocorasick
  Running setup.py clean for pyahocorasick
Failed to build pyahocorasick
Installing collected packages: pyahocorasick, textsearch, contractions
    Running setup.py install for pyahocorasick ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\catka\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nx9373pl\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nx9373pl\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-82y3clbc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'ahocorasick' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DAHOCORASICK_UNICODE= -Ic:\users\catka\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\catka\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" /Tcpyahocorasick.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyahocorasick.obj
    pyahocorasick.c
    c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\Automaton_pickle.c(363): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
    c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\Automaton_pickle.c(422): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
    c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\Automaton_pickle.c(473): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
    c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\Automaton_pickle.c(483): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
    c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\src/custompickle/load/loadbuffer.c(68): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
    c:\users\catka\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\src/custompickle/load/module_automaton_load.c(89): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    creating C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nx9373pl\pyahocorasick\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\catka\anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\catka\anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_ahocorasick build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyahocorasick.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ahocorasick.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ahocorasick.cp37-win_amd64.lib
    pyahocorasick.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_ahocorasick' specified multiple times; using first specification
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ahocorasick.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ahocorasick.cp37-win_amd64.exp
    Generating code
    Finished generating code
    LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\catka\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nx9373pl\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CatKa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nx9373pl\\pyahocorasick\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\CatKa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-82y3clbc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Download, install, set env variables and perhaps reboot

Comment: What would be env variables in this case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error even Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610212/pip-error-even-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-installed)

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: I would suggest using Conda, particularly on windows. In any case, this is a duplicate, have you done any research?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29846087/11301900

Comment: @phd followed the instructions here (https://www.scivision.co/python-windows-visual-c-14-required/) from the second link you pasted but still nothing... idk if I'm still missing something, but I downloaded the "Windows 10 SDK" thing and restarted the computer

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes, I already updated setuptools and tried some of the answers in that link you gave me, but still nothing. Also, it can't be installed on conda.

Comment: @user12195705 Windows 10 SDK?

Comment: @user12195705 You’re getting the same error message as before?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 SDK... I don't really know how to check if it's installed properly tho. And the new error is on EDIT2 on the original post.

Comment: I see a different error now: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+LINK+fatal+error+LNK1158%3A+cannot+run+%27rc.exe%27

Answer (score 5):

I received the same error using pip installation and tried "conda Channel" for installation  and it is successful.

Try below commands in the Powershell prompt of Anaconda Navigator

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install pyahocorasick
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me after installing build tools for visual studio c++ 14.0