# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools" scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to install scrapy on my window 10 laptop. I have installed " Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017" on my PC. I am still getting below error:

[image]

```
python version: 3.6, 64bit
OS: Windows 64 bit
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to install pre-compiled python liblaries from: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Most likely you will need to install "Twisted" as well. Just download both open cmd and use:

pip install [liblary name]

pip install Twisted-18.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl