# Visual studio required for pycrypto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto

I am a newbie to Python. So, please be gentle

I tried to install pycrypto to use `encryption and deceryption`. I used the Python command `pip install pycrypto`. On running the command received the following error:

```
error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'
```

1) Since the error refers Microsoft visual studio, does Visual studio have to be installed to install pycrypto? I've verified the path in the system (already have visual studio for C# projects). I've the path - `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\vc\`, but PlatformSDK folder does not exist

2) `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\vc\` - May I know why it refers VC?

3) If visual studio not required, what do I've to do fix the error?

Additional info - I've Python 3.7 installed in the machine.

**UPDATED: As per Moses answer, Pycryptodome does not require Microsoft Visual C++ and I could install without any issue. But yet to test code against library**

Comment: @Tomothy32 set USERPROFILE - This gives my `C:\users\currentusername`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44953739/1709397) answer may help you get past the installation problem you are facing. As for alternatives to pycrypto on Python 3.7, you could try [PyCryptodome](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: I can not Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0  as I do not have control for installation. Thank you for PyCryptodome. I installed it. I am trying to see the feature difference of Pycrytpo and Pycrytpodome. Can you provide some details on it?

Comment: PyCryptodome is a fork of PyCrypto. It is actively maintained and has all the functions provided by PyCrypto. It has been tested on Windows with Python 3.5. Have a look at the documentation.