# Error in installing jsonlib in python using cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, json-lib

I was trying to install the jsonlib in python using pip install, but the error keeps coming

I've tried installing the Visual Studio C++ redis. 2015-2019.
It did nothing.

```
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/55/19c29fd79dfb5d42f4568feedc5a286d01d0683a372c1e19024531576508/jsonlib-1.6.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: jsonlib
  Building wheel for jsonlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\satyam porwal\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Satyam Porwal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-w6n5pwbu\\jsonlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Satyam Porwal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-l33ly_ta' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying jsonlib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  running build_ext
  building '_jsonlib' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for jsonlib
  Running setup.py clean for jsonlib
Failed to build jsonlib
Installing collected packages: jsonlib
  Running setup.py install for jsonlib ... error
```

I expected to install the json

Comment: After installing vc++ ,did you reopen cmd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Answer (score 0):

> pipwin installs unofficial python package binaries for windows
>   provided by Christoph Gohlke here

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install jsonlib
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for python 3.x oon windows

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install jsonlib-python3
```