# Getting error Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required, but already have Microsoft Visual C++ 15-19 installed

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install jupyter notebook but error occurred and is "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required". And i already have Visual 2015-2019 installed on my PC and I am unable to find setup of Visual C++ 2014 particularly. Please assist how it can be resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual Studio Build tools from

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing it with Anaconda? I've had similar issues where I unknowingly try to install the old version of a package, and it asked me to have Microsoft Visual C++ 14. But I was able to fix it by finding an updated, compatible version of the same package. So maybe Anaconda would give you the latest version of Jupyter Notebook that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `python -m pip install jupyterlab` command only worked for me after installing the Windows SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/

If it still doesn't work try installing this: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
Choose the C++ package. It will take about 5GB of space and a restart.