# pip install textacy fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, textacy

I am trying to install textacy to perform NLP tasks, but getting an error while trying to do:

```
python -m pip install textacy --user
```

The code starts running but after a while it fails and shows this output:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe' 'C:\Users\3ORM3OV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-owdv11_a\normal' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel 'preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2' 'thinc<7.4.0,>=7.3.0' 'murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0' 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (57 lines):
  Collecting wheell
-LINKS TO PACKAGES DELETED SO AS TO BE ABLE TO POST-
  Installing collected packages: wheel, cymem, murmurhash, preshed, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, plac, tqdm, thinc, cython
      Running setup.py install for cymem: started
      Running setup.py install for cymem: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fx2lzonc\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fx2lzonc\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v5xmg2ww\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-owdv11_a\normal' --compile
           cwd: C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fx2lzonc\cymem\
      Complete output (24 lines):
      WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      copying cymem\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      copying cymem\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      package init file 'cymem\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem\tests
      copying cymem\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem\tests
      copying cymem\cymem.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      copying cymem\cymem.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      copying cymem\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      running build_ext
      building 'cymem.cymem' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-3.7
      creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\cymem
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /EHsc /Tpcymem/cymem.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\cymem/cymem.obj /Ox /EHsc
      cymem.cpp
      c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include\pyconfig.h(203): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fx2lzonc\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fx2lzonc\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v5xmg2ww\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-owdv11_a\normal' --compile Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe' 'C:\Users\3ORM3OV\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-owdv11_a\normal' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel 'preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2' 'thinc<7.4.0,>=7.3.0' 'murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0' 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2' Check the logs for full command output.>
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install textacy --user`? I just did and it works fine for me.

Comment: Do you have both python 2 and python 3 installed?

Comment: Have a look through these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c1083+basetsd.h

Comment: @Linny Running that code outputs this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: @Stephopolis I guess I only have v3, should I have both?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying running without the `--user` flag? I ran `python -m pip install textacy` and achieved a successful installation. You might be having some issues with the user prefix.

Comment: Tried that too, error still shows up:  "Installing backend dependencies ... error" :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0?

Use the link to [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.). That will install Visual C++ 14.0 without installing Visual Studio.

After installing it, the command worked for me.

```
pip install textacy
```

Importantly, I found the answer from here: [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Answer (score 0):

**To install **textacy** package with conda run one of the following:**

```
conda install -c conda-forge textacy
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 textacy
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 textacy
```

I Tried the below code from the above three. It worked fine for me

```
conda install -c conda-forge textacy
```

**For Reference** -
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/textacy

Note-Run the code in anaconda prompt/cmd