# pip cannot install SciPy, error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: python, django, scipy, pycharm

I tried to install SciPy, but it fails and tells me I need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0.

With Python 2.7 I was able to install it just fine, but now with Python 3.8 it does not work.
Also I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 installed, which is version 14.24, so I guess this should be fine?

Any ideas?

EDIT: I think I made a little bit of progress, but I get a different error now.

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
```

This is the long version

```
Collecting scipy
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/ab/e2eb3e3f90b9363040a3d885ccc5c79fe20c5b8a3caa8fe3bf47ff653260/scipy-1.4.1.tar.gz
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: still running...
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Preparing wheel metadata: started
Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
Complete output from command C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3sh6cvka:
setup.py:418: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\scipy\pip-wheel-metadata'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
Running from scipy source directory.
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\Tim\\Documents\\Python_Docs\\untitled\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Tim\\Documents\\Python_Docs\\untitled\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
customize PGroupFlangCompiler
Could not locate executable flang
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_clapack_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Tim\\Documents\\Python_Docs\\untitled\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

flame_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\Tim\\Documents\\Python_Docs\\untitled\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

accelerate_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Tim\\Documents\\Python_Docs\\untitled\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9dno1q7l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9dno1q7l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
  NOT AVAILABLE

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 197, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 69, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
  File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9dno1q7l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    self.run_setup()
  File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9dno1q7l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 242, in run_setup
    super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
  File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9dno1q7l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
    exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
  File "setup.py", line 540, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 536, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9dno1q7l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "setup.py", line 435, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError(msg)
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.

----------------------------------------

Command "C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Python_Docs\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3sh6cvka" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\scipy
```

After that I wanted to try to install SciPy with a binary from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy). But now I do not really know what to do with this file, how do I install it?

Greets, Tim

Comment: What you need are the VS C++ build tools. Are those installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Show the error, show details. Seems like your is not trying to get wheels, but to compile it. The latter will be nearly impossible, not because of visual studio, but because of the annoying fortran-dependencies. So: analyze why it's not grabbing the pre-built wheels.

Comment: I did install VS C++ build tools, but I still can't install SciPy, I updated my post with more information on that..

Comment: No need for any msvc stuff. And dont mix gohlkes binaries with a non gohlke numpy. There is still no info on how you tried it. Gui in pycharm vs cmd pip install. When doing this with pycharm, you need to understand it. When doing this without pycharm, there is no way it will not grab binaries, at least not on a non-broken python install. The blas/lapack you showed is the start of the more serious install trouble and yet you did not reach the fortran dependencies. Again: if its trying t compile, you are on the wrong path.Why not just try a fresh pyhon without pycharm following scipy docs first

Comment: I tried it with both pycharm and with the cmd pip install. It's actually a clean Python, installed it yesterday after realizing I had accidentally installed the 32 bit version. I will try it on another clean Python installation and without pycharm later today.