# Getting error while installing `pandas-profiling`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-profiling

Need Help I want to install pandas-profiling in python 3.8.2 but when i try to install the package i am facing errors.

`pip install pandas-profiling`

I am getting this error

`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'f:\data analaysis\fbi crime rate\newenv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Manish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vz1xsz_s\\astropy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Manish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vz1xsz_s\\astropy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-011lkvam\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'f:\data analaysis\fbi crime rate\newenv\include\site\python3.8\astropy' Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 as it says?

Comment: No this error is common while installing some libraries

Comment: Ok. Have you checked out the top answers from these other people having the same issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: it wasn't compulsory to install the visual c++ 14..... whenever i face errors while installing some packages i install via the .whl file so i looked for this library to but its not available

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio [changed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/) the [Build Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/11/02/visual-studio-build-tools-now-include-the-vs2017-and-vs2015-msvc-toolsets/) from being C++ specific in late 2017. Thus newer Visual Studio versions work in place of older versions.

Install using any ONE of these choices:

1. Microsoft [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16).
2. Alternative link to Microsoft [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019).
3. Offline installer: [vs_buildtools.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe)
4. [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.)

Select: Workloads → Desktop development with C++, then for Individual Components, select only:

- Windows 10 SDK
- C++ x64/x86 build tools

The build tools allow using MSVC “cl.exe” C / C++ compiler from the command line.

Why this is necessary?

Windows Python needs Visual C++ libraries installed via the SDK to build code, such as via setuptools.extension.Extension or numpy.distutils.core.Extension. For example, building [f2py](https://www.scivision.co/tags/f2py) modules in Windows with Python requires Visual C++ SDK as installed above. On Linux and Mac, the C++ libraries are installed with the compiler.