# "The system cannot find the path specified." at the beginning of cmd

Tags: cmd, anaconda

I ran the command prompt with administrator privilege to uninstall Ananconda on my computer, after the process, I reopened the cmd and found this line, "The system cannot find the path specified" at the beginning of my cmd.

I can guarantee that my cmd did not have this line before, how can I manage to fix it? Is it a serious bug that I should be aware of?

Thank you.

["The system cannot find the path specified."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XBB9.jpg)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the Registry Editor (Windows key and type `regedit` in the prompt)
Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` and clear the values.
If it exists in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`, delete it as well.

Comment: How if it does not exist in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, exist in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` but no `AutoRun`?