# Multiple "The system cannot find the path specified" messages on running "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmd, command-line, visual-studio-2019

When I run Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 I each time got multiple messages:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.7.3
** Copyright (c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I didn't find the same question from other users when I was looking for a solution. I already did repair VS via Visual Studio Installer but this change nothing. How to fix it?

Comment: run [processmonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and look which operation result in NOT_FOUND

Comment: @magicandre1981 I see in processmonitor too much "spam". There is continuously updated list of processes, about 800k lines already. How to find there something and don't go crazy.

Comment: in timeline look when the CMD is started and excluded everything from before. next remove BUFFER_OVERFLOW

Comment: @magicandre1981 there is nothing with `NOT_FOUND`. Only `SUCCESS`, `FAST_IO_DISALLOWED` and `NOT_REPARSE_POINT`

Comment: @magicandre1981 I find something. Looks can't found `reg.*` files. https://imgur.com/a/DjmYGIv

Comment: I doubt that this is the cause. Exclude all SUCCESS results to filter even more down

Comment: @magicandre1981 I also note when I run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" in console, got following output: https://pastebin.com/nQyAyYqm

Comment: @magicandre1981 I can't understand what happens. I exclude all `SUCCESS` messages but there too much paths which ends on `\set*` and have status `NO_SUCH_FILE`

Comment: `4000` event shown related to my filter. it's not easy to find here what I need

Comment: Have fixed the issue by clear `Command Processor\AutoRun` value in `regedit`. Accordingly to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62808833/6135469

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The system cannot find the path specified." at the beginning of cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62808726/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-at-the-beginning-of-cmd)

Comment: ok, thanks for the follow up. I never seen this before. Nice to hear that you fixed it.