# The system cannot find the file specified in Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio

Running Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022

Previously, I didn't get this error.

After try some attempt modifying the shortcut launcher using administrator, this error happens. Roll back the path and command for the launcher, keeps this error.

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.1.3
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools>
```

How to fix this?

---

I've read this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62808833/11671779) but, in my case, there is already no `AutoRun`.

---

Open the `.bat` file from cmd also did not work.

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools> VsDevCmd.bat
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.1.3
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Modify` and `Repair` from `Visual Studio Build Tools` solve the problem.

Make sure to check some optional download shown here:[image] (if you can't open imgur, here is the [image](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/cpp/msvc/desktop_development_with_cpp.png)).

See this VSCode tutorial [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) on installing Visual Studio Build Tools.

Comment: I followed your solution twice, but it doesn't work for me. Leaving this here for others to confirm.

Comment: @Christian Other tutorial and step by step installation that help me is this one [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.2_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2019_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29). Hope you able to install or fix your installation issue.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think OP launched the correct file for VS Build Tools 2022.

The correct one would be `Launch-VsDevShell.ps1`:

```
C:\Users\Administrator> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\Launch-VsDevShell.ps1'
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer PowerShell v17.5.4
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
C:\Users\Administrator>
```

The console above is from my Windows 2022 server with VS Build Tools 2022 installed.

Also, observe that you can also use [this official PowerShell module](https://github.com/Microsoft/vssetup.powershell) from Microsoft to find the installation directory of the VS Build Tools:

```
C:\Users\Administrator> $buildToolsHome = Get-VSSetupInstance | Select -ExpandProperty InstallationPath
C:\Users\Administrator> & "${buildToolsHome}\Common7\Tools\Launch-VsDevShell.ps1"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer PowerShell v17.5.4
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
C:\Users\Administrator>
```