# "ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyq which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly" when installing PyQ?

Tags: anaconda, kdb, pyq, embedpy

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered any similar errors when attempting to install PyQ for Windows? I've tried both Anaconda and the Windows prompt and there doesn't appear to be any difference in the errors produced.

Any help is much appreciated!

I've included the link to a screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vofnr.png

Comment: What lead to that error, what is the context for this? As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try install VS code for C++ before installing PyQ, or you can install PyQ on Linux if possible.

Comment: The VS code for C++ is up to date, I've tried updating and running again but no luck.

Comment: check it's 64bit, think you need 64bit as looking at the error. Looks to be 64bit PyQ you have. Should also be using 64bit kdb if you aren't already

Answer (score 1):

The issue was you need to have VS 2017 instead of the most recent version as PyQ for Windows isn't up to date with this regard (at the time of this writing, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`