# How to resolve error of installing pyaudio

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

I tried to install pyaudio, but it is showing error.

Steps I tried to resolve this problem:

1. I tried every solution available on this website - [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
2. I installed c++ build tools.
3. I installed mingw.
4. I installed Microsoft Visual c++ greater than 14.0

And the result i got:[See the error in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxDZY.png)
NOTHING!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Comment: As suggested by @AMC check share link and try to install it using pip and downloaded .whl package from  ifd.uci.edu pip binary repository

Answer (score 0):

did you try this ? check if you have portaudio in your pip freeze  ( which OS are you encountering this)

First step - pkg install portaudio

After install

Second step - pip install pyaudio