# pip install web3 giving same error even after installing everything

Tags: python

I am getting this error. I already installed Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019 and also Windows 10 SDK but still same error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9p_6k287\\bitarray_31255b19323a43b99b5e92b09ec2cb61\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9p_6k287\\bitarray_31255b19323a43b99b5e92b09ec2cb61\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5pof_7tn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\bitarray'
         cwd: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9p_6k287\bitarray_31255b19323a43b99b5e92b09ec2cb61\
    Complete output (13 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    copying bitarray\test_bitarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    copying bitarray\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    copying bitarray\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    copying bitarray\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    running build_ext
    building 'bitarray._bitarray' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9p_6k287\\bitarray_31255b19323a43b99b5e92b09ec2cb61\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9p_6k287\\bitarray_31255b19323a43b99b5e92b09ec2cb61\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5pof_7tn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\bitarray' Check the logs for full command output.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIvi5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says you need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 on your machine, here is the link with a question with a similar issue:

[Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44953739/9676887)

I hope this can solve your issue.