# We3.py Install Error: Running setup.py install for bitarray ... error ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, web3py, brownie

I am using python 3.9.7
PS C:\Program Files\Python39> pip install web3
...
This is the part where it's in red error message:

```
  Running setup.py install for bitarray ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\QUI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8r0e8eer\\bitarray_3b8d63f53f724d4f910c7c1d5014a41b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\QUI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8r0e8eer\\bitarray_3b8d63f53f724d4f910c7c1d5014a41b\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\QUI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-107_ynkk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\QUI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\bitarray'
     cwd: C:\Users\QUI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8r0e8eer\bitarray_3b8d63f53f724d4f910c7c1d5014a41b\
Complete output (13 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
copying bitarray\test_bitarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray    copying bitarray\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray    
copying bitarray\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
copying bitarray\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray     
running build_ext
building 'bitarray._bitarray' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with
```

"Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\QUI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8r0e8eer\bitarray_3b8d63f53f724d4f910c7c1d5014a41b\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\QUI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8r0e8eer\bitarray_3b8d63f53f724d4f910c7c1d5014a41b\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\QUI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-107_ynkk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\QUI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Include\bitarray' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Take a look at the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required).

Comment: @SadraSabouri thank you, I "Modify" installation to include the Visual C++ build tools and run: pip install --upgrade setuptools. After restarting the machine then it works.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).