# pip install python-pkcs11 Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip, command-prompt, pkcs#11

So, I know this question is asked quite a lot in here, but I executed the `pip install python-pkcs11` and pip threw this error

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

And even though I've tried almost every single solution in [here](https://github.com/benfred/implicit/issues/76), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required), [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4160) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/136595/error-microsoft-visual-c-140-or-greater-is-require.html), I am still stuck in this problem.
Honestly, I am getting desperate because none of it worked and I don't know what to do anymore.
So, if anyone can help me, I'd greatly appreciate.

Here's the complete error pip install log:

```
> PS C:\Users\AYRTO> pip install python-pkcs11 Collecting python-pkcs11 
> Using cached python-pkcs11-0.7.0.tar.gz (106 kB)   Preparing metadata
> (setup.py) ... done Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto in
> c:\users\ayrto\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
> (from python-pkcs11) (1.5.1) Requirement already satisfied:
> cached-property in
> c:\users\ayrto\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
> (from python-pkcs11) (1.5.2) Building wheels for collected packages:
> python-pkcs11   Building wheel for python-pkcs11 (setup.py) ... error 
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> 
>   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.   │ exit
> code: 1   ╰─> [52 lines of output]
>       C:\Users\AYRTO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27:
> SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated.
> Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
>         warnings.warn(
>       running bdist_wheel
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\defaults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\mechanisms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\dh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\dsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\ec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\rsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\x509.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       running egg_info
>       writing python_pkcs11.egg-info\PKG-INFO
>       writing dependency_links to python_pkcs11.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
>       writing requirements to python_pkcs11.egg-info\requires.txt
>       writing top-level names to python_pkcs11.egg-info\top_level.txt
>       listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
>       reading manifest file 'python_pkcs11.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>       writing manifest file 'python_pkcs11.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>       copying pkcs11\_errors.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\_mswin.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\_pkcs11_defn.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\_utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       running build_ext
>       cythoning pkcs11/_pkcs11.pyx to pkcs11\_pkcs11.c
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:219:70: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:590:63: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:616:51: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:656:64: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:903:56: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:947:74: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:957:67: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:994:55: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:1038:74: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:1048:67: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:1084:52: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:1125:65: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:1217:59: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       warning: pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx:1478:64: Use boundscheck(False) for faster access
>       building 'pkcs11._pkcs11' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
>       [end of output]
> 
>   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-pkcs11  
> Running setup.py clean for python-pkcs11 Failed to build python-pkcs11
> Installing collected packages: python-pkcs11   Running setup.py
> install for python-pkcs11 ... error   error:
> subprocess-exited-with-error
> 
>   × Running setup.py install for python-pkcs11 did not run
> successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [40 lines of output]
>       C:\Users\AYRTO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27:
> SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated.
> Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
>         warnings.warn(
>       running install
>       C:\Users\AYRTO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34:
> SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use
> build and pip and other standards-based tools.
>         warnings.warn(
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\defaults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\mechanisms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\dh.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\dsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\ec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\rsa.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\x509.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       copying pkcs11\util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11\util
>       running egg_info
>       writing python_pkcs11.egg-info\PKG-INFO
>       writing dependency_links to python_pkcs11.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
>       writing requirements to python_pkcs11.egg-info\requires.txt
>       writing top-level names to python_pkcs11.egg-info\top_level.txt
>       listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
>       reading manifest file 'python_pkcs11.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>       writing manifest file 'python_pkcs11.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>       copying pkcs11\_errors.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\_mswin.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\_pkcs11.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\_pkcs11_defn.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       copying pkcs11\_utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pkcs11
>       running build_ext
>       skipping 'pkcs11\_pkcs11.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
>       building 'pkcs11._pkcs11' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
>       [end of output]
> 
>   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip. error: legacy-install-failure
> 
> × Encountered error while trying to install package. ╰─> python-pkcs11
> 
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: "And even though I've tried almost every single solution in here, here, here and here" What happened when you tried each one of them? For example, what happened when you tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, as explained in the top answer of the second link?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can install the full package from github

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools