# cx_Freeze does not seem to import nor install using pip

Tags: pygame, cx-freeze

When I try to import CX_Freeze I get this error:

[image]

But I tried to compile a pygame script I made anyways and I got this error:

[image]

If you can help me that would be great.
Thank you

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the error trace!

Answer (score 0):

try the below command to see you installed packages:

```bash
pip list
```

If you do not see `cx_Freeze` displayed in the list try to install by this command:

```bash
pip install --upgrade cx_Freeze
```

Comment: I did that but when I try to install it, it gives me an error I look at the list, and it's not there.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required) you can see how you can upgrade your c++ and then you can install `cx_Freeze` via pip.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you need to install or update Microsoft Visual C++ to 14.0 or greater. If you don't want to, try other modules such as py2exe
See also:
https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe

Comment: Please remember that you need to run `pip install cx_Freeze` again after installing Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater