# I am trying to install cx_Oracle in VS code and getting the error Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, python-oracledb

Collecting cx-oracle
Using cached cx_Oracle-8.3.0.tar.gz (363 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: cx-oracle
Building wheel for cx-oracle (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for cx-oracle (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [7 lines of output]
C:\Users\bhide\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ivxi5iqh\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\expand.py:144: UserWarning: File 'C:\Users\bhide\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c848lmx4\cx-oracle_9ca450826f5b4ec282380d54992f5870\README.md' cannot be found
warnings.warn(f"File {path!r} cannot be found")
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'cx_Oracle' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cx-oracle
Failed to build cx-oracle
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cx-oracle, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

How can i get solve this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, you are using Python 3.11. There are no pre-built cx_Oracle 8.3 packages for that version.  Upgrade to the latest cx_Oracle, now called python-oracledb, which does have pre-built packages for the latest Python.  With this, you won't need a compiler.

See the [python-oracledb release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

In summary, run:

```
python -m pip install oracledb
```