# i want install obfsproxy using pid

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I want install obfsproxy using pid command at python
I running this command pip install obfsproxy and seeing below error:
I installed Visual C++ 14.0, but still i see it on error
What more should i install?

C:\python3\Scripts>pip install obfsproxy

```
Collecting obfsproxy
  Using cached obfsproxy-0.2.13-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python3\lib\site-packages (from obfsproxy) (65.5.0)
Collecting PyCrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting Twisted
  Using cached Twisted-22.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 MB)
Collecting argparse
  Using cached argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting pyptlib>=0.0.6
  Using cached pyptlib-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyyaml
  Using cached PyYAML-6.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (143 kB)
Collecting zope.interface>=4.4.2
  Using cached zope.interface-5.5.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (211 kB)
Collecting constantly>=15.1
  Using cached constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.9 kB)
Collecting incremental>=21.3.0
  Using cached incremental-22.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Automat>=0.8.0
  Using cached Automat-22.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting hyperlink>=17.1.1
  Using cached hyperlink-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
Collecting attrs>=19.2.0
  Using cached attrs-22.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.5
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting twisted-iocpsupport<2,>=1.0.2
  Using cached twisted-iocpsupport-1.0.2.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyCrypto, twisted-iocpsupport
  Building wheel for PyCrypto (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [149 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto
      copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto
      copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Hash
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Cipher
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Util
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Protocol
      copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Protocol
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\PublicKey
      copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\PublicKey
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Signature
      copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\Crypto\Signature
      running build_ext
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyCrypto
  Running setup.py clean for PyCrypto
  Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'twisted_iocpsupport.iocpsupport' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport
Failed to build PyCrypto twisted-iocpsupport
ERROR: Could not build wheels for twisted-iocpsupport, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

and my python version is below:

```
C:\python3>python
Python 3.11.2
```

i have updated pip and python

i installed node.js for install most things and now i have below errors:

```
C:\python3\Scripts>pip install obfsproxy
Collecting obfsproxy
  Using cached obfsproxy-0.2.13-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python3\lib\site-packages (from obfsproxy) (67.6.0)
Collecting PyCrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting Twisted
  Using cached Twisted-22.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 MB)
Collecting argparse
  Using cached argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting pyptlib>=0.0.6
  Using cached pyptlib-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyyaml
  Using cached PyYAML-6.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (143 kB)
Collecting zope.interface>=4.4.2
  Using cached zope.interface-5.5.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (211 kB)
Collecting constantly>=15.1
  Using cached constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.9 kB)
Collecting incremental>=21.3.0
  Using cached incremental-22.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Automat>=0.8.0
  Using cached Automat-22.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting hyperlink>=17.1.1
  Using cached hyperlink-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
Collecting attrs>=19.2.0
  Using cached attrs-22.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.5
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting twisted-iocpsupport<2,>=1.0.2
  Using cached twisted-iocpsupport-1.0.2.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyCrypto, twisted-iocpsupport
  Building wheel for PyCrypto (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      winrand.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(33): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: syntax error: ','
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(53): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(55): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(61): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(68): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(74): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(81): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(87): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(94): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(100): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyCrypto
  Running setup.py clean for PyCrypto
  Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for twisted-iocpsupport: filename=twisted_iocpsupport-1.0.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl size=39179 sha256=74bcd92b802828eae58abeb6c5e7d72da535b4c4163e3e9eede0e6300b8f4e06
  Stored in directory: c:\users\kiyan-co\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\a2\79\c1\a53c8342856dd9111dcdee0e278d3d3a4c856573a4a3ab3568
Successfully built twisted-iocpsupport
Failed to build PyCrypto
Installing collected packages: twisted-iocpsupport, pyptlib, PyCrypto, incremental, constantly, argparse, zope.interface, typing-extensions, six, pyyaml, idna, attrs, hyperlink, Automat, Twisted, obfsproxy
  Running setup.py install for PyCrypto ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for PyCrypto did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      winrand.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(33): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: syntax error: ','
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(53): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(55): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(61): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(68): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(74): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(81): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(87): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(94): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(100): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> PyCrypto

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

C:\python3\Scripts>
```

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required) helps?

Comment: @Sergiu i received new error after installed node.js please see post again, i edited it.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the node.js mention, I don't see anything related to it.