# ERROR: Failed building wheel for maxvolpy

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, conda

I'm trying to install the package maxvolpy (https://github.com/c-f-h/maxvolpy), but I am coming across a couple of errors:

```
 python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully
```

```
 No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
```

```
error: legacy-install-failure
```

I tried both using the pip install

```
pip install maxvolpy
```

and also setting up from the repo

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/muxas/maxvolpy
cd maxvolpy
python setup.py install
```

but both have failed. What other approaches can I use?

EDIT: The full error message from the pip approach is

```
Collecting maxvolpy
  Using cached maxvolpy-0.3.8.tar.gz (12 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.1 in c:\users\waqas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from maxvolpy) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cython>=0.23.4 in c:\users\waqas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from maxvolpy) (0.29.15)
Building wheels for collected packages: maxvolpy
  Building wheel for maxvolpy (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [31 lines of output]
      non-existing path in 'maxvolpy': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl'
      non-existing path in 'maxvolpy': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include'
      non-existing path in 'maxvolpy': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib'
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building extension "maxvolpy._maxvol" sources
      build_src: building npy-pkg config files
      C:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\cross.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\maxvol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\__version__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      running build_ext
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
      building 'maxvolpy._maxvol' extension
      compiling C sources
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for maxvolpy
  Running setup.py clean for maxvolpy
Failed to build maxvolpy
Installing collected packages: maxvolpy
  Running setup.py install for maxvolpy ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for maxvolpy did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [31 lines of output]
      non-existing path in 'maxvolpy': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl'
      non-existing path in 'maxvolpy': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include'
      non-existing path in 'maxvolpy': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib'
      running install
      C:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building extension "maxvolpy._maxvol" sources
      build_src: building npy-pkg config files
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\cross.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\maxvol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      copying maxvolpy\__version__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\maxvolpy
      running build_ext
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
      building 'maxvolpy._maxvol' extension
      compiling C sources
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> maxvolpy

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

EDIT: As recommended in [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required) I installed Microsoft Visual C++ , however the issue is still not resolved. I still get the same error message above.

Using the approach where I clone into the github repo, I however now get a new error message:

```
non-existing path in 'maxvolpy': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl'
non-existing path in 'maxvolpy': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include'
non-existing path in 'maxvolpy': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib'
running install
C:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "maxvolpy._maxvol" sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_py
running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
building 'maxvolpy._maxvol' extension
compiling C sources
C:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py:546: UserWarning: Fallback spawn triggered. Please update distutils monkeypatch.
  warnings.warn("Fallback spawn triggered. Please update distutils monkeypatch.")
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DSCIPY_MKL_H -DHAVE_CBLAS -IC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\windows\mkl -IC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\windows\mkl\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\windows\mkl\lib -IC:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\Library\include -IC:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /Tcbuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.obj
_maxvol.c
C:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(1148): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__pyx_t_double_complex'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(1148): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(1153): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(1153): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(1153): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(1160): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__pyx_t_float_complex'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(1160): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(1165): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__pyx_t_float_complex_from_parts'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(1165): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(1165): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2133): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2133): error C2081: '__pyx_t_float_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2133): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2133): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2133): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2134): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2134): error C2081: '__pyx_t_float_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2134): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2134): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2134): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2135): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2135): error C2081: '__pyx_t_float_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2135): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2135): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2135): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2136): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2136): error C2081: '__pyx_t_float_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2136): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2136): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2136): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2137): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2137): error C2081: '__pyx_t_float_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2137): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2137): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2137): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2138): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2138): error C2081: '__pyx_t_float_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2138): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2138): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2138): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2139): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2139): error C2081: '__pyx_t_double_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2139): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2139): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2139): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2140): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2140): error C2081: '__pyx_t_double_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2140): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2140): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2140): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2141): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2141): error C2081: '__pyx_t_double_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2141): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2141): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2141): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2142): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2142): error C2081: '__pyx_t_double_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2142): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2142): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2142): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2143): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2143): error C2081: '__pyx_t_double_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2143): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2143): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2143): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2144): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2144): error C2081: '__pyx_t_double_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2144): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2144): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2144): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2149): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2149): error C2081: '__pyx_t_float_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2149): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2149): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2149): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2150): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2150): error C2081: '__pyx_t_float_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2150): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2150): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2150): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2151): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2151): error C2081: '__pyx_t_double_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2151): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2151): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2151): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2152): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2152): error C2081: '__pyx_t_double_complex': name in formal parameter list illegal
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2152): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2152): error C2059: syntax error: ','
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2152): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2189): error C2065: '__pyx_t_float_complex': undeclared identifier
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(2190): error C2065: '__pyx_t_double_complex': undeclared identifier
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(3550): warning C4013: '__pyx_f_8maxvolpy_7_maxvol_crect_maxvol' undefined; assuming extern returning int
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(3550): error C2065: '__pyx_t_float_complex': undeclared identifier
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(3550): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(3635): warning C4013: '__pyx_f_8maxvolpy_7_maxvol_zrect_maxvol' undefined; assuming extern returning int
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(3635): error C2065: '__pyx_t_double_complex': undeclared identifier
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(3635): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(4446): warning C4013: '__pyx_f_8maxvolpy_7_maxvol_cmaxvol' undefined; assuming extern returning int
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(4446): error C2065: '__pyx_t_float_complex': undeclared identifier
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(4446): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(4519): warning C4013: '__pyx_f_8maxvolpy_7_maxvol_zmaxvol' undefined; assuming extern returning int
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(4519): error C2065: '__pyx_t_double_complex': undeclared identifier
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(4519): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(4903): warning C4305: '=': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(5371): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(9470): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c(9470): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DSCIPY_MKL_H -DHAVE_CBLAS -IC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\windows\mkl -IC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\windows\mkl\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\windows\mkl\lib -IC:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\Library\include -IC:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\waqas\Anaconda3\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /Tcbuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.7\maxvolpy\_maxvol.obj" failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). You've only posted excerpts here.