# cant install jenkins using pip

Tags: python, pip

```
C:\code>pip install jenkins
Collecting jenkins
  Using cached jenkins-1.0.2.tar.gz (8.2 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: jenkins
  DEPRECATION: jenkins is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for jenkins ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for jenkins did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\python\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      copying jenkins.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      running build_ext
      building 'lookup3' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> jenkins

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Tried:
[Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Getting this error:
[image]

Installed went fine via the UI as mentioned in the comment:
[image]
[image]

Still no luck. Any suggestions?

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559, you can add `--use-pep517` in pip command:

```
pip install --use-pep517 jenkins
```

and make sure you have Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or [greater](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

It was python-jenkins and not jenkins. I wonder why they named it like this.